# Datagrid binding to Multi Check Selection

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

[Re wrote rhe question to be a little clearer on what it is I'm trying to do]

Hoping someone can help me as I've been chasing my tail for hours. Trying to get to grips with WPF as the GUI output reflects what I am looking for more than WinForms.

I've got 3  controls:

Combobox

Checklistbox

Datagrid

I have a dataset with a Datatable set up with relationships between the 3 tables I need to query for results.
This is my XAML.

```
 <xctk:CheckListBox DataContext="{Binding Path=NAME, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Source={StaticResource _Regions__Terminal_ViewSource}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource _Regions__Terminal_ViewSource}}" Margin="17,108,13,71" Name="clb_Terminals" SelectedItems="{Binding}" SelectedMemberPath="IsSelected" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedValue}" ValueMemberPath="Level" DisplayMemberPath="NAME" />
                        <Button Content="Refresh Forecast View" Height="48" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,288,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220" />
                        <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="GROUPNAME" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource _Regions_ViewSource}}" Margin="22,52,0,0" Name="_Regions_ComboBox" SelectedValuePath="GROUPNUM" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="215">
                            <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Advanced" Name="tabItem2">
                    <Grid />
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Height="380" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource _Regions__Terminal_GridViewViewSource}}" Margin="297,15,0,0" Name="gridViewDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1148" DataContext="{Binding}" GridLinesVisibility="None">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="sTATNUMColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=STATNUM}" Header="STATNUM" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="jDEColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=JDE}" Header="JDE" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="cONTRACTColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=CONTRACT}" Header="CONTRACT" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="sTATIONNAMEColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=STATIONNAME}" Header="STATIONNAME" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="tOWNColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=TOWN}" Header="TOWN" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="tRIPTIMEColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=TRIPTIME}" Header="TRIPTIME" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="tERMINALColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=TERMINAL}" Header="TERMINAL" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="mAXSIZEColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=MAXSIZE}" Header="MAXSIZE" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

So far the 3 controls are bound through parent / child relationships but it isn't working quite as I had hoped and I'm a bit out of my depth.

I select my region from the combobox which successfully populates my checklistbox with the respective terminals. What I need to do next is when each terminal is checked it filters the Terminal column on my datagrid to show only corresponding recordsets matching the terminals ticked.

I also seem to have a strange problem in that the default combobox selection (region1) which then populates two terminal names returns nothing in the datagrid. This I can't understand as even without the filters the datagrid returns results for every other selection. (Checked my tables and tested some queries and doesn't appear to be the table data).

I tried this in my code behind:

```
 public ObservableCollection<CheckedItem> List { get; set; }

    public class CheckedItem
    {
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

However I also need to define the DisplayMemberName of the checkboxlist else it fails to return the correct values. The problem here being I cannot use an itemlist in XAML simultaneously.

Anyway spent 6hrs trying to make this work and hopelessly lost. Would be very grateful for any direction or help.

Using VS2010 WPF .net 4.

Comment: Can you post some code. Its a bit hard to understand at the moment